# Как разделить одну строку на много строк по словам?

Tags: delphi

Есть такие строки

```
************************   0   0 -145 -242 -348 -346 -96 -74 -38 -550 -551 -545 -594
********************   0 635 568 433 344 303 388 486 493 262 -125 -334 -465 -643
```

А на выходе хочу получить

```
************************   
0   
0
-145
-242
-348
...
```

Как такое сделать правильно ?

Comment: да собственно ExtractStrings

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы, воспользовался методом который предложил Alshabalin, все работает =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Delphi explode() function like PHP explode()](http://www.jasonwhite.co.uk/delphi-explode-function-like-php-explode/)

Использовать так:

```
explode(' ', '************************   0   0 -145 -242 -348 -346 -96 -74 -38 -550 -551 -545 -594', 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Советую вам особо не заморачиваться по этому поводу, так как задача эта является чуть ли не классической у программистов. Лучше посмотрите стандартный модуль **[StrUtils](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils)**, который создан специально для работы со сторками.

**UPD**

Для вашей задачи вполне сойдет вот [эта функция](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.SplitString)

Answer (score 0):

Тут, вероятно, где-то +1 надо дописать, где-то -1 итд, в общем отладить, но логика должна быть ясна.

```
function DoIt(S: string): string;
var
  SL: TStringList;
  I, N: Integer;
begin
  Result:= '';
  SL:= TStringList.Create;
  try
    N:= 1;
    for I:= 1 to Length(S) do
    begin
      if S[I] = ' ' then
      begin
        SL.Add(Copy(S, N, I - N));
        N:= I;
      end;
    end;
    Result:= SL.Text;
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```